# Remove space between textboxes and buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My code is as follows: I want to remove the spaces between the `textboxes` and button, so all 3 elements are stuck to one another. How can I get this done.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-12  ">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="#" role="form" class="form-inline">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control " placeholder="Email Address" required>

                    </div>
                    <div class=" form-group col-md-4 span7 ">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control " placeholder="Email Address" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" form-group col-md-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle " type="submit">Sign up for free</button>
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Can you share it on jsfiddle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 remove space between inline inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736686/bootstrap-3-remove-space-between-inline-inputs)

Comment: The JSFindle is as follows. http://jsfiddle.net/2n9AH/24/

Comment: You can do something like this: http://www.bootply.com/LSENRHkcrl

Comment: @sinisake It should ideally align to the center of the panel too. and the form elements should not contain any spaces in between

Comment: You can use pull-left class to remove spaces completelly... regarding centering - don't have idea. :)

Comment: Why are you using col-md with form input elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it will stuck all the elements together.

I just removed the form-group class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-12  ">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="#" role="form" class="form-inline">

                    <div class=" col-md-4 ">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control " placeholder="Email Address" required>

                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-md-4 span7 ">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control " placeholder="Email Address" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="  col-md-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle " type="submit">Sign up for free</button>
                    </div>


                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its still the same. There are spaces between the textboxes and buttons.

Comment: Check the link. Doesn't seem to work.  http://www.bootply.com/0qmwOtGcNj

Comment: You need to drag the screen to your left so the output expands then you'll see all the spaces.

Comment: All form elements now aligns together but the panel is not centered. Do you know how I could fix this ?

Comment: No problem. Happy coding. :)